# Create location sensitive map Ammaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ammap

I have an array like this:

```
Lat/long.
[{-13123,-21312},{-13123,-21312},{-12123,-21312}]
```

**OBS: the values may repeat.**

How can I display an amMap of the kind [location sensitive](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/location-sensitive-map/) based on these datas  using % of occurrences  ?. I've not found anything in the docs, please help.

A jsfidle will be awesome.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, and even how it relates to the demo you referred to which does an IP lookup of the country you are browsing for and displays corresponding country map.

Comment: i want to print the map darker based on the group of lat and long pointing to its country

Comment: Based how? If the whole of the country falls withing those coordinates? Part of the country?

Comment: so it will sum the number to the country , for example:

2 coordinates eua , EUA = 2 , 
3 to brasil , BRAISL MAP = 3 
and so on...

i need it becouse i have to mensure the number of users by country in the map.

Exactly the same as here http://keyhole.co/

Comment: Got it. I'm afraid you can't do that with amMap directly. It does not have any geolocation services. You will need to use some sort of 3rd party gelocation service, like geonames.org to resolve those coordinates to countries, then sum up in your code and show aggregated values in map.

Comment: Also, this sounds like a job for a server-side script. What if you have a million users? Then you'd be pumping a million coordinates back and forth between the server and client, doing the resolution every time. It's very inefficient and a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: thanks @martynasma you have absolute right, please can you create a map with numbers inside the countryies like the heat map example , i cant see where it puts the contents inside the map, i want a worl map with random numbers, just this i will get it trought server side then.

Comment: i found this https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv
how can i discover if a lat and long belongs to a country based on this ?. thanks alot.

Comment: I don't think this info is good for that. I suppose you should create a separate ticket - the one that would deal about determining a country based on the IP.

Comment: not ip , based on the lat and long.

Comment: found it , just need the map with fixed values.