# amCharts Unbalanced

Tags: javascript, node.js, amcharts

I'm trying to create an amCharts chart, based on three values but the result is completely messed up: the chart goes completely to the left, doesn't pin all the node results or shows all the data.

Please Help

```
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "none",
        "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
        "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        "valueAxes": [{
            "id":"v1",
            "axisAlpha": 0,
            "position": "left"
        }],
        "graphs": [{
            "id": "g1",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
            "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "bulletSize": 5,
            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "title": "red line",
            "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
            "valueField": "Tweets"
        },
                  {
            "id": "g2",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
            "bulletColor": "#00FF00",
            "bulletSize": 5,
            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "title": "green line",
            "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
            "valueField": "Retweets"
        }],
        "chartScrollbar": {
            "graph": "g1",
            "scrollbarHeight": 30
        },
        "chartCursor": {
            "cursorPosition": "mouse",
            "pan": true,
             "valueLineEnabled":true,
             "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true
        },
        "categoryField": "date",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": true,
            "dashLength": 1,
            "minorGridEnabled": true,
            "position": "top"
        },
        exportConfig:{
          menuRight: '20px',
          menuBottom: '50px',
          menuItems: [{
          icon: 'http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/export.png',
          format: 'png'   
          }]  
        },
        "dataProvider": 
                    [{"date":"2016-03-11","Tweets":96,"Exposure":633286,"Retweets":73},{"date":"2016-03-10","Tweets":235,"Exposure":1637137,"Retweets":48},{"date":"2016-03-09","Tweets":116,"Exposure":657912,"Retweets":30},{"date":"2016-03-08","Tweets":98,"Exposure":510558,"Retweets":129},{"date":"2016-03-07","Tweets":91,"Exposure":930904,"Retweets":58},{"date":"2016-03-06","Tweets":20,"Exposure":56490,"Retweets":6},{"date":"2016-03-05","Tweets":22,"Exposure":134128,"Retweets":13},{"date":"2016-03-04","Tweets":40,"Exposure":263687,"Retweets":60},{"date":"2016-03-03","Tweets":35,"Exposure":477493,"Retweets":17},{"date":"2016-03-02","Tweets":39,"Exposure":541723,"Retweets":70}]

    }
);

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();
function zoomChart(){
    //chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
    chart.zoomToIndexes(0, 10);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srp8313j/52/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of data points is important. For date-based charts, the data points need to come in ascending order, from oldest to the newest. While in your data they are running backwards. To fix this, simply change the order of the data points:

```
"dataProvider": [
  {"date":"2016-03-02","Tweets":39,"Exposure":541723,"Retweets":70},
  {"date":"2016-03-03","Tweets":35,"Exposure":477493,"Retweets":17},
  {"date":"2016-03-04","Tweets":40,"Exposure":263687,"Retweets":60},
  {"date":"2016-03-05","Tweets":22,"Exposure":134128,"Retweets":13},
  {"date":"2016-03-06","Tweets":20,"Exposure":56490,"Retweets":6},
  {"date":"2016-03-07","Tweets":91,"Exposure":930904,"Retweets":58},
  {"date":"2016-03-08","Tweets":98,"Exposure":510558,"Retweets":129},
  {"date":"2016-03-09","Tweets":116,"Exposure":657912,"Retweets":30},
  {"date":"2016-03-10","Tweets":235,"Exposure":1637137,"Retweets":48},
  {"date":"2016-03-11","Tweets":96,"Exposure":633286,"Retweets":73}
]
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srp8313j/53/).

Comment: worked, thanks a lot, may be you can help me in this one too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925718/create-location-sensitive-map-ammaps